# Write OpenCV image in memory to BytesIO or Tempfile

Tags: python, opencv

I need to write an OpenCV image that sits in memory to a BytesIO or Tempfile object for use elsewhere.

I am concerned this is a dead end question, because `cv2.imwrite()` takes a filename as an argument, and then uses the file extension to infer the image type to write (`.jpg`, `.png`, `.tiff`, etc.). `cv2.imwrite()` does this at the C++ level, so I am concerned that there is no way to successfully pass a non-filename object to it.

The other possible solution is converting to `PIL` through `numpy`, which has the capacity to write to `BytesIO` and `Tempfile` objects, but I want to avoid needless copies.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[cv2.imencode](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) may help you:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import io

img = np.ones((100, 100), np.uint8)

# encode
is_success, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)
io_buf = io.BytesIO(buffer)

# decode
decode_img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(io_buf.getbuffer(), np.uint8), -1)

print(np.allclose(img, decode_img))   # True
```