# Save images obtained from OpenCV on another computer (using FTP or other way)

Tags: python, opencv, ftp

I am taking pictures using the OpenCV from my webcam, and after I have identified the face, I save the face image using a `cv2.imwrite` in a folder in my computer.

Now, my question is how can I save the images in path on another computer?

I mean, for example, using FTP, I can directly add another path to storing the images to `cv2.imwrite` and put them in the another computer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`cv2.imencode`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#cv2.imencode) to [store the image to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52865771/850848):

```
retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
```

Then upload the `buffer`:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from io import BytesIO

ftp = FTP('ftp.example.com')
ftp.login('username', 'password')

flo = BytesIO(buffer)
ftp.storbinary('STOR test.jpg', flo)
```