# Python: SpooledTemporaryFile suffix not working

Tags: python, opencv, temporary-files

I want to write an image using opencv to a temporary file, get the path of that temporary file and pass that path to a function.

```
import cv2 as cv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile, SpooledTemporaryFile

img = create_my_awesome_image()

with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png") as temp:
    print(temp.name)
    cv.imwrite(temp.name, img) # this one sparks joy

with SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=1000000, suffix=".png") as temp:
    print(temp.name)
    cv.imwrite(temp.name, img) # this one does not
```

The first print prints `C:\Users\FLORIA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpl2i6nc47.png`.
While the second print prints: `None`.

Using `NamedTemporaryFile` works perfectly find. However, because the second print prints None, I cannot use the `SpooledTemporaryFile` together with opencv. Any ideas why the prefix argument of `SpooledTemporaryFile` is ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a spooled file (such as a `SpooledTemporaryFile`)  doesn't exist on the disk, so it also doesn't have a name.

However, note that `cv2.imread()` will take a file name as an argument, meaning that it will handle the file opening and it doesn't support spooled files.

If you are only working with `png` images, they are not encoded, meaning that the variable `img` already contains the image data in memory and there is nothing else for you to do, just call `cv2.imwrite()` when you want to save it to the disk. If you want to use a temporary file, it has to be a `NamedTemporaryFile`.

If you want to handle an encoded image format in memory, such as `jpg`, you can use `cv2.imencode()` for that purpose, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52865864/8250094).