# Is there a way to convert numpy array to PNG/JPG... payload without saving it as a file?

Tags: numpy, opencv, png

Suppose there exists a numpy array, `data`. I am trying to do the equivalent of the following

```
cv2.imwrite(filename, data)
with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
     data_compressed = filename.read()
```

without having to write to a file. Is there a way to convert numpy array to its equivalent PNG/JPG... representation without having to write to a file and read it as binary?

Comment: cv.imencode(...)

Comment: As @Miki already pointed out, here an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52865864/19042045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Miki pointed out, `imencode(...)` is the solution.