# Can't correctly decode an image frame using PyAV

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyav

I'm trying to simply encode and decode a capture frame from the web-cam. I want to be able to send this over TCP but at the moment I'm having trouble performing this just locally.

Here's my code that simply takes the frame from the web-cam, encodes, then decodes, and displays the two images in a new window. The two images look like this:

[image: 1]

Here's the code:

```
import struct
import cv2
import socket
import av
import time
import os

class PerfTimer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_time = time.perf_counter()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"'{self.name}' taken:", end_time - self.start_time, "seconds.")

os.environ['AV_PYTHON_AVISYNTH'] = 'C:/ffmpeg/bin'

socket_enabled = False
sock = None
if socket_enabled:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Connecting to server...")
    sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8000))

# Set up video capture.
print("Opening web cam...")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)

# Initialize the encoder.
encoder = av.CodecContext.create('h264', 'w')
encoder.width = 800
encoder.height = 600
encoder.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'
encoder.bit_rate = 5000

# Initialize the decoder.
decoder = av.CodecContext.create('h264', 'r')
decoder.width = 800
decoder.height = 600
decoder.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'
decoder.bit_rate = 5000

print("Streaming...")
while(cap.isOpened()):
    
    # Capture the frame from the camera.
    ret, orig_frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Source Video', orig_frame)

    # Convert to YUV.
    img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(orig_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV_I420)

    # Create a video frame object from the num py array.
    video_frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img_yuv, format='yuv420p')

    with PerfTimer("Encoding") as p:
        encoded_frames = encoder.encode(video_frame)

    # Sometimes the encode results in no frames encoded, so lets skip the frame.
    if len(encoded_frames) == 0:
        continue

    print(f"Decoding {len(encoded_frames)} frames...")

    for frame in encoded_frames:
        encoded_frame_bytes = bytes(frame)

        if socket_enabled:
            # Get the size of the encoded frame in bytes
            size = struct.pack('<L', len(encoded_frame_bytes))
            sock.sendall(size + encoded_frame_bytes)

        # Step 1: Create the packet from the frame.
        packet = av.packet.Packet(frame)

        # Step 2: Decode the packet.
        decoded_packets = decoder.decode(packet)

        for packet in decoded_packets:
            # Step 3: Convert the pixel format from the encoder color format to BGR for displaying.
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(packet.to_ndarray(format='yuv420p'), cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420)

            # Step 4. Display frame in window.
            cv2.imshow('Decoded Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# release everything
cap.release()
sock.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: confusing names: "decoded packets" aren't packets but frames. -- a bitrate is in bits. 5000 bits (per second) is highly questionable. -- also, this isn't an opencv issue. you use pyav for decoding, not opencv.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. You're right. I'm bouncing between PyAV, ffmpeg-python and OpenCV trying to get this working.

Comment: @MartinBlore - If you just need to encode/decode, you can do it via imdecode. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52865864/1874627. I dont see why use ffmpeg in between.

Comment: @saurabheights Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to encode a video feed from the web-cam, stream that over a TCP socket to a server and decode it on the other end for displaying. I'd rather not send uncompressed raw data over the socket. At the moment Im just trying to test a local loop.

Comment: @MartinBlore - See imencode - https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63 . It does perform compression and does it in memory, thus not involving disk IO.

Comment: @saurabheights Image compression yes, not video compression using a codec such as avc1 or h264. Thanks though :).

Comment: the problem here is threefold. (1) you're actually doing it right, i.e. using video compression. (2) everyone else does it wrong (imencode on individual video frames). (3) everyone else doesn't realize what they're doing, so *you* are the heretic.

Comment: @MartinBlore - Yeah, my bad. I had written a comment with my mistake of using image compression but deleted it since it additionally had more wrong information :D. Moving on, can you set framerate in encoder - `encoder.framerate=30` and test. Its working on my end.

Comment: https://imgur.com/V0vf85h . You can ignore the dots, they are in the pic due to using IntelRealsense camera which has an active emitter for Stereo matching - depth map calculation.

Comment: Interesting how you got that to work. I've now changed things to use a BytesIO object, I use av.open and add a stream to it, then use the stream.encode/container.mux, I can then grab the bytes from the BytesIO buffer. I use those bytes in a new container/stream, and demux/decode, and now I get everything running perfectly. I Can't seem to adjust the bit-rate at all though...

Comment: New code: https://pastebin.com/J7RCySBc

Comment: @MartinBlore - Try changing CRF(tested and works, but I dont think it will give exact control on bitrate). See - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: @saurabheights Got it! All working now! Thank everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

A bitrate is given in bits. 5000 bits (per second) is very little.

Give it 5000000 bits/sec and see what happens.

The naming in your code is misleading. Your "decoded packets" aren't packets but **frames**.

Comment: Bit rate increased dramatically, this is the result: https://i.imgur.com/EPLlAAX.png

Comment: Before I waste anymore of your time though, I will try and remove the use of PyAv and see if I can stick to OpenCV for doing this. I have doubts about the byte boundaries both libs might be assuming.

Comment: writing into a socket may only write some of what you passed. it always returns the number of bytes that were actually written. `sendall()` should take care of that... but perhaps your sockets code is the issue. remove it from the equation, just roundtrip the encoding and decoding.

Comment: any type conversion (`bytes()`) should also be scrutinized. it may not be required, and it may be hiding errors, or convert data into the wrong format.

Comment: let the compression run for several frames. the encoder may need time to adjust its quantization to reach the target bitrate.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Christoph, the main issue is the low `bit_rate`.

The `bit_rate` setting is meaningless if we don't set the `framerate`.
The average number of bits per frame is the bitrate divided by the framerate, so the encoder must know the framerate for setting the destination bits per frame.

Without setting the framerate there is a warning message:

> MB rate (1900000000) > level limit (16711680)

---

We have to set the bitrate and the framerate (example):

```
encoder.bit_rate = 5000000
encoder.framerate = 25
```

---

For making a reproducible code sample, we may use synthetic video frames, instead of grabbing frames from the camera (it helps for testing).

I tried to use the correct terminology (packets versus frames issue) as mentioned by Christoph.

The code sample includes some suggestions in the comments:

```
import struct
import cv2
import socket
import av
import time
import os
import numpy as np


def make_sample_image(i, width, height):
    """ Build synthetic "raw BGR" image for testing """
    p = width//60
    img = np.full((height, width, 3), 60, np.uint8)
    cv2.putText(img, str(i+1), (width//2-p*10*len(str(i+1)), height//2+p*10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, p, (255, 30, 30), p*2)  # Blue number
    return img


class PerfTimer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_time = time.perf_counter()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"'{self.name}' taken:", end_time - self.start_time, "seconds.")

#os.environ['AV_PYTHON_AVISYNTH'] = 'C:/ffmpeg/bin'  # We are not using FFmpeg CLI

socket_enabled = False
sock = None
if socket_enabled:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Connecting to server...")
    sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8000))

# Set up video capture.
#print("Opening web cam...")
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)  # We are going to use make_sample_image instead of cap.read()
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800)
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)

# Initialize the encoder.
encoder = av.CodecContext.create('h264', 'w')
encoder.width = 800
encoder.height = 600
encoder.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'
encoder.bit_rate = 5000000
encoder.framerate = 25  # Set the framerate - the bitrate is not meaningful without a framerate (or without frame period).
#encoder.options = {'tune': 'zerolatency'}  # Consider adding "-tune zerolatency" for reducing the latency.
#encoder.open()

# Initialize the decoder.
decoder = av.CodecContext.create('h264', 'r')
#decoder.width = 800  # There is no need to set width, height, pix_fmt, bit_rate for the decoder.
#decoder.height = 600
#decoder.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'
#decoder.bit_rate = 5000
#decoder.open()

print("Streaming...")
#while (cap.isOpened()):    
for i in range(1000000):
    # Capture the frame from the camera.
    #ret, orig_frame = cap.read()

    # Use synthetic frame for testing.
    orig_frame = make_sample_image(i, encoder.width, encoder.height)

    cv2.imshow('Source Video', orig_frame)

    # Convert to YUV.
    img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(orig_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV_I420)

    # Create a video frame object from the NumPy array.
    video_frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img_yuv, format='yuv420p')
    #video_frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(orig_frame, format='bgr24')  # BGR is also supported...

    #video_frame.pts = i  # We may want to set the timestamps
    #video_frame.time_base = encoder.time_base

    #with PerfTimer("Encoding") as p:
    #    encoded_frames = encoder.encode(video_frame)
    encoded_packet = encoder.encode(video_frame)  # The correct terminology is "encoded_packet".

    # Sometimes the encode results in no frames encoded, so lets skip the frame.
    if len(encoded_packet) == 0:
        continue

    print(f"Decoding {len(encoded_packet)} packets...")

    #for frame in encoded_packet:  # No need to use a for loop - there is always going to be only one encoded packet.
    #encoded_frame_bytes = bytes(frame)
    encoded_packet_bytes = bytes(encoded_packet[0])

    if socket_enabled:
        # Get the size of the encoded frame in bytes
        size = struct.pack('<L', len(encoded_packet_bytes))
        sock.sendall(size + encoded_packet_bytes)

    # Step 1: Create the packet from the frame.
    #packet = av.packet.Packet(frame)

    # Step 1: Create the packet from the "bytes".
    packet = av.packet.Packet(encoded_packet_bytes)

    # Step 2: Decode the packet.
    #decoded_packets = decoder.decode(packet)
    decoded_video_frames = decoder.decode(packet)  # After decoding, the terminology is "decoded_frames"

    if len(decoded_video_frames) > 0:
        # Step 3: Convert the pixel format from the encoder color format to BGR for displaying.
        decoded_video_frame = decoded_video_frames[0]
        decoded_frame = decoded_video_frame.to_ndarray(format='yuv420p')
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(decoded_frame, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420)
        #frame = decoded_video_frame.to_ndarray(format='bgr24')  # BRG is also supported...

        # Step 4. Display frame in window.
        cv2.imshow('Decoded Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# release everything
#cap.release()
if socket_enabled:
    sock.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```